# Batch script to find the first word of all the lines in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can anybody help me in deriving the logic for getting the first word of all the lines present in a text file using a batch script??

Comment: Well... How must we do that? You provided nothing to work with.

Comment: You keep on coming online to see if there is an answer, as you'll notice, no one will answer as we do not know what you want. So either update your question to make it clear or delete it.

Comment: You haven't even explained things sufficiently so that somebody would offer you a solution for your off-topic question. The title of your question specifically asks about finding the first word of all lines in a text file, so given these three lines: `99 Red Baloons`, `Top 100 questions` and `Gtrest is incorrect`, do you want `Red` `Top` and `is`?

Comment: `for /F %%a in (theFile.txt) do echo %%a`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% confident if i'm answering the question correctly, but here's what I put together anyway. Assuming that each first word in the file is followed by a space, this script should work. Just copy and paste it into a batch file and you're good to go,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims= " %%i in ('type "[FILENAME].txt"') do (
   set "str=%%i"
   echo !str:  =!
)
pause
```

So, for example, if I had a text file called "text.txt" with the contents (Not real information),

```
Hello There!
My name is John
I live in England
I am 20 years old
```

Using this script,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims= " %%i in ('type "text.txt"') do (
   set "str=%%i"
   echo !str:  =!
)
pause
```

will give me the following output,

```
Hello
My
I
I
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Of course, if you want to get rid of the last line, change the

```
pause
```

at the end to a

```
pause > nul
```

to get the following output

```
Hello
My
I
I
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: When you use the `delims=...` switch in `for /F` command, the returned tokens does _not_ contain the delimiters. The _default_ delimiters are the space and the TAB characters.